# Creating a virtual environment returns No such file or directory

Tags: python

When I try `python3 -m venv venv`, terminal returns

```
python3: posix_spawn: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.82.7:No such file or directory
```

I have seen other posts mentioning Home Brew related issues but I doubt this is the case. I did try uninstalling and installing Python.

Note: I was connected to localhost with a virtualenv. When I tried again later on, this was returned. I am building a Flask application.

Comment: does `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.82.7` exist?

Comment: it doesn't. There is python3.8. Why would it look for python3.82.7? What could be the reason that python3.82.7 is not there?

Comment: maybe you should open that folder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/ and check the file name..

Comment: You probably have `python` aliased to something weird. What does `type -all python` produce and if that is a script or wrapper, what does that contain?

Comment: @hanleilei that file (python3.82.7) is not there. The same error is returned when I try to install flask again, for instance. How to fix this?

Comment: This looks like it's aliased to `${something}2.7` where the expectation is that `something` would perhaps be `/usr/local/bin/python` and you would have installed `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` and `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`; but of course this breaks down if `something` is set to something unexpected which does not adhere to this design.

Comment: @tripleee it returns  python is /usr/bin/python

Comment: Does `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/` contain a binary with a more promising-looking name? Can you trace how it gets to the point where it tries to access this path? (On Linux I would suggest `strace` but it's more complicated on Mac, where you need root access to do things like that. If you can find a good `dtrace` tutorial it might be worth a shot, but it's a deep rabbithole.)

Comment: Are you using some wrapper like `pyenv` or etc? How exactly have you installed Python? Python 3 is still not available as a native Mac installation I believe, and there are multiple ways to install it (most commonly Homebrew, but there are several other reasonably popular competitors). (Unless you are on Catalina, it seems?)

Comment: @tripleee No, I am not using anything like that. I previously used Python3.7 but then after this error, I uninstalled it and installed 3.8 in python.org/downloads.

Comment: @tripleee I am on Mojave. Could opening another folder in workspace while being connected to localhost affect this? Because Vscode shows 'Connection got disposed'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204140/discussion-between-antero-ukkonen-and-tripleee).

Comment: Sorry, not in a place where I can chat, and I don't think I can help further with this. It looks to me like a pretty specifically Mac problem so you might want to [edit] the question to include the additional information I have asked for in comments (probably with still more details), and probably add a Mac tag too.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use pipenv library for creating the virtual environment.

```
pipenv install pipenv
```

for example:

```
mkdir testapp
cd testapp
pipenv shell
```

Now the virtual environment is ready.
Then to install libraries in the virtual environment instead of "pip" you have to use "pipenv".
For example:

```
pipenv install requests
pipenv install flask
```

Then to write the requirements.txt you can use

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

To uninstall libraries:

```
pipenv uninstall requests
```

Each time to work on the virtual environment:

```
pipenv shell
```

How to exit the virtual environment?

```
exit
```