# Using venv on the app for iPad: “Pyto - Python 3“

Tags: python, ipad, python-venv

I want to use a virtualenv for a python project in “Pyto - Python 3”. For create a virtual environment I go to the “Ron module” option in pyto and I type `venv venv_name`. How can I open the virtualenv and install some modules? With “Ron module” I can’t open the directory of the file activate just typing `venv_name/bin/activate` or `venv_name\Scripts\activate` Because the app type automatically the command `python -m`.

Edit: With pyto I can create the virtualenv whit out problem

I even try to use the module `pipenv` but this happened:

```
python -m pipenv shell
Documents/site-packages/pipenv/patched/crayons.py:154: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \$
  "([^-_a-zA-Z0-9!@#%&=,/'\";:~`\$\^\*\(\)\+\[\]\.\{\}\|\?\<\>\\]+|[^\s]+)"
Documents/site-packages/pipenv/patched/crayons.py:154: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \$
  "([^-_a-zA-Z0-9!@#%&=,/'\";:~`\$\^\*\(\)\+\[\]\.\{\}\|\?\<\>\\]+|[^\s]+)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp/PRMFC.repl.py", line 53, in _main_function_no_one_calls_a_function_like_that
    runpy._run_module_as_main(module_name)
  File "Library/python38/runpy.py", line 195, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "Library/python38/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    cli()
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 429, in shell
    do_shell(
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2356, in do_shell
    ensure_project(
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 576, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 493, in ensure_virtualenv
    if not project.virtualenv_exists:
File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 271, in virtualenv_exists
    if os.path.exists(self.virtualenv_location):
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 470, in virtualenv_location
    self._virtualenv_location = self.get_location_for_virtualenv()
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 294, in get_location_for_virtualenv
    return str(get_workon_home().joinpath(self.virtualenv_name))
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 2016, in get_workon_home
    mkdir_p(str(expanded_path))
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1488, in mkdir_p
    mkdir_p(head)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1488, in mkdir_p
    mkdir_p(head)
  File "Documents/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1493, in mkdir_p
    os.mkdir(newdir)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '.local'
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308862/creating-a-virtual-environment-returns-no-such-file-or-directory/59310032#59310032

Comment: Hi arun, i tried to use that method but it doesn’t work (I edit the post)